# How To Send Variable From Parent Class to Child Custom Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewController with class file ViewController.h&m that contains a UIView, but the UIView has a custom class file drawView.h&m, which is referenced in to ViewController.m by #import "drawView.m". I would like to set a UIColor variable (could be any color) in ViewController.m and pass it and read it in drawView.m.

I know how to pass variables from one view controller class file to another ViewController class file, but it doesn't seem to work the same way for passing it to a UIView class file. Please help.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UserDafaults save the `UIColor` in `ViewController` and get the color and used in custom class `UIView`.

Check below code:

Save `UIColor` to `UserDafaults`

```
NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorData forKey:@"myColor"];
```

Get `UIColor` from `UserDafaults` as:

```
NSData *colorData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myColor"];
UIColor *color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
[self.txtMobNo.layer setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting color In ViewController viewWillApear or viewDidLoad or after viewWillApear or viewDidLoad  to make sure drawView is loaded properly.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   // Any color that u want to use
   UIColor * color =[UIColor redColor];

   if([self.drawView)
   {
      // applyeColor is drawview's custom method
      [self.drawView applyColor:color];
  }
  else
  {
   NSlog (@"drawView is nil");
  }
}
```